# How to show JAAS LoginException on error page

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat8, jaas

I am using JAAS and form based web authentication on a Tomcat 8.x web server.
There are many possible reasons why a user gets denied access when trying to log in:

1. invalid username
2. invalid password
3. doesn't have account in database
4. account in database is not active
5. account in database doesn't have required roles
6. etc....

In my LoginModule, I check for all these conditions and more, and throw a LoginException if the user should not be allowed to access the web app.
JAAS seems to catch the thrown LoginException, throw it away, and redirect the user to the error page specified in the web.xml .

I have spent hours and hours googling around trying to find a way to obtain the reason for the login exception but have come up empty.

Is there any way for the error page to find out the reason why the LoginException was thrown?

Comment: At the point the exception is thrown, is the HttpServletRequest available?  If yes, then set an attribute which can be referenced and displayed on the error page.  However, consider if this is really safe to do.  For example, if the exception is from an invalid password the error page would say something like "invalid password".  This tells a hacker the username is good, just an invalid password.  Similar with the other attributes which give hints to a hacker on how to attack.  The exception could be logged but the details should not be displayed to the user.

Comment: No, neither the http servlet request, response, nor session is available during the login() or commit() methods of javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule

Answer (score 4):

> 1. invalid username
> 2. invalid password

You should not distinguish these two cases. Doing so constitutes an information leak to the attacker, by reducing his search space once he has found a valid username. You should just report 'invalid username/password combination' or similar.

> 3. doesn't have account in database

This is identical to (1).

> 4. account in database is not active

This again should not be distinguished, as above.

> 5. account in database doesn't have required roles

This is not a login failure. This becomes an access denial when the user performs something that requires a missing role, or it causes the user interface not to display actions for the missing roles.

The solution I adopted to passing appropriate JAAS errors out to the application was to add them as public credentials of the `Subject`.

Comment: I disagree, and this doesn't answer the question of how to propagate information back to the error page from JAAS. Simply telling a user there was an error does them no good.  A user can keep retrying their username/password for eternity and it won't matter if they don't have a entry in the database or if the database entry has been marked inactive.  Differentiating between an invalid username and password does indeed give information to an attacker though, as you stated.

Comment: I can't figure out from all that whether you are agreeing or disagreeing with both me and @AndrewS about information leakage, but you are totally and utterly incorrect to assert that my suggestion about using public credentials in the `Subject` as the information propagation path doesn't answer the question. It does, and it works. It can only be assumed that you didn't read that far.

Comment: Sorry.  I did not see the part about adding the login error message to the Subject's public credentials.  Thanks very much for the suggestion.  That seems like a brilliant solution, but I can't find code to retrieve the Subject outside of the LoginModule.  I tried the following, but it did not work: Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());  How does one retrieve the Subject outside of the LoginModule?